# Is it possible to convert the type of a character into numeric while maintaining the character itself?

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, character, numeric

let's say I have this df

```
df = data.frame(x = c('1E','1E','2F','2F','3F','3E','4E'),
                y = LETTERS[1:7] )
```

The first column (x) is of type character. I just want to change the type to numeric while maintaining the same variable (meaning that the variable x would still have letters. However its type will become numeric).

Comment: Could you calrify the "*while maintaining the character itself*" part? Or better yet, what would the resulting dataframe look like?

Comment: A column cannot be numeric and have characters in it. You can maybe have labels on it?

Comment: What’s your larger goal? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Please explain the bigger picture. Why is this needed? We may be able to help with the actual problem, I suspect this is an XY problem

Comment: As is, the OP's request is Impossible.

Comment: The problem is that I have IDs that are made of combinations of many repeated numbers and the letters E and F. and I need to use a function called `f.spade`. However this function presents an error that the ID column must be numeric. And for the work, I need to maintain these IDs so I can't use other fabricated numeric IDs.

Comment: where can we find the docs to this `f.spade` function?

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(x1 = readr::parse_number(x))
```

-output

```
   x y x1
1 1E A  1
2 1E B  1
3 2F C  2
4 2F D  2
5 3F E  3
6 3E F  3
7 4E G  4
```

Comment: but the x column would still be character. My point is that even with the existance of letters, I want the type of variable x to become numeric (without deleting the letters). I know it's weird as a request but I was wondering if such a thing exists.

Comment: @Anas116 with a character in it, it can't be numeric `class`

Comment: @Anas116 you could have `attr(df, "xval") <- readr::parse_number(df$x)`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a `factor`.

```
(df$x <- as.factor(df$x))
# [1] 1E 1E 2F 2F 3F 3E 4E
# Levels: 1E 2F 3E 3F 4E
```

where

```
mode(df$x)
# [1] "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_extract` with regex [0-9+]:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x1 = as.numeric(str_extract(x, '[0-9+]'))) 


 x     y        x1
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 1E    A         1
2 1E    B         1
3 2F    C         2
4 2F    D         2
5 3F    E         3
6 3E    F         3
7 4E    G         4
```

Answer (score 1):

you may have to create a new ID col, recoding x by unique values.
A hacky way would be to convert to factor, then to numeric.
This would create a new numeric ID.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(new_id = as.numeric(as.factor(x)),
           .after = x)

   x new_id y
1 1E      1 A
2 1E      1 B
3 2F      2 C
4 2F      2 D
5 3F      4 E
6 3E      3 F
7 4E      5 G
```